# How to pass arguments from a class to inside its two functions?

Tags: python, function, class, parameter-passing

I want to know how can I pass argument from a class to two different functions inside. I `import` this file, called test.py and I have to pass two arguments `(name_t,name_s)` from another file suppose caledl passing.py. So I want to do is like this (I know it's wrong but it is to explain my point):

(passing.py)

```
from test import M

name_t = 'tomas'
name_s = 'santino'

M(name_t,name_s)
```

(test.py)

```
class M():
    def values():
        tapi = name_t
        
    def loop():
        symbol = name_s
```

Comment: The class needs an `__init__` method to get the parameters.

Comment: It should set attributes of `self`, which the other methods can access. Any tutorial on OOP should show how to do this.

Comment: I don't understand what you want the code to do, but you should probably try to follow a tutorial rather than asking on Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't make sense because you don't seem to understand the underlying theory yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `__init__()` method to get the parameters and set attributes.

```
class M():

    def __init__(self, name_t, name_s):
        self.tapi = name_t
        self.symbol = name_s

    def values(self):
        print(self.tapi)
        
    def loop(self):
        print(self.symbol)

name_t = 'tomas'
name_s = 'santino'

m = M(name_t, name_s)
m.values()
m.loop()
```